# Alien visiting earth forgets he is an alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read this short story a long time ago. It may have been written in the 60s or earlier.

An alien is visiting earth incognito but has an accident of some kind, has amnesia, and doesn't know he is an alien. He gets a factory job but suddenly remembers who he is and now has to figure out how to get in touch with his fellow aliens (I guess his ship or whatever it is has been destroyed).

He invents a gadget that is useful to humans but that also broadcasts in some faster-than-light way. The broadcasts are heard by his fellows and they rescue him.

There were some nice touches in how the alien viewed humans. If it's not in an anthology it should be.

Comment: Shades of "The Forgotten Door", but not quite....

Comment: I remember this... but from where? Anyway, that confirms the original publication date as likely to be 40s through 60s.

Comment: I remember reading something like this in the early 1970s, probably in an HC anthology from a library.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good summary of "[Exile](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55850)", by Everett B. Cole, although the planet in question is not specifically Earth, but an early-industrial Earth-like planet.

All I have access to is my paperback version of "5 Tales of Tomorrow", but it says that the story is copyright 1953, looks like it was published in [the January 1954 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57496) of *Astounding Science Fiction*.

Comment: can be found here https://archive.org/details/sim_astounding-science-fiction_1954-01_52_5/page/8/mode/1up thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was the story I was looking for. And thanks for the pointer to the archive.org issue of Astounding.